# $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{[3x]}{[x]!}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I saw an interesting definite integral at somewhere and would like to share.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{[3x]}{[x]!}dx$$

The solution given is

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{[3x]}{[x]!}dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{[3x]}{[x]!}dx$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left ( \int_{k}^{k+\frac{1}{3}}\frac{3k}{k!}dx+\int_{k+\frac{1}{3}}^{k+\frac{2}{3}}\frac{3k+1}{k!}dx+\int_{k+\frac{2}{3}}^{k+1}\frac{3k+2}{k!}dx \right )$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left ( \frac{1}{3}\left ( \frac{3k}{k!} \right )+\frac{1}{3}\left ( \frac{3k+1}{k!} \right ) +\frac{1}{3}\left ( \frac{3k+2}{k!} \right )\right )=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{3k+1}{k!}=3\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$$
$$=3e+e-1=4e-1$$

I wonder is there another way to solve this definite integral?

Comment: The first limit should be over $n$, not $k$

Comment: And there is no need to take limits over $n$: put directly $\sum_{k=1}^\infty.$ Apart from that, it seems the most natural and easy way. Why do you find this integral "interesting"?

Comment: @AnneBauval: it is not obvious at first that the integral is convergent, so the limit is necessary. Of course, since the integrand is nonnegative, the only options are convergent or $\infty$, so it is not that bad, but if the question comes from a standard Calculus course, it is important to do things rigorously.

Comment: @Taladris. I agree with you and the problem is interesting.

Comment: Though it is quite obvious that the integral is convergent, it was not my first thought. Rather, all the quantities we write being nonnegatve, avoiding that heaviness is better than "not that bad": it is asolutely rigorous, and should be taught as such in a standard calculus course (I did).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Interesting problem and nice solution.*

Doing the same kind of work, if $n$ is an integer, I think that we may conjecture that
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor n x\rfloor }{\lfloor x\rfloor !}\,dx=\frac {4e} 3 n-1 $$

I *think* that
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\lceil n x\rceil }{\lceil x\rceil !}\,dx=\frac {e} 2 n+\frac 13 $$

Try to prove if I am correct or not with the second.